# Sign an array of bytes with X509 Certificate in .Net Core

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-core, sign, pkcs#12

I want sign an array of bytes with `X509Certificate2`,

Here are a sample for [.Net Framework 4.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.cmssigner?view=netframework-4.7), but I need the same for .Net Core:

```
 var argCertFirmante = new X509Certificate2(file, pass);
 var infoContenido = new ContentInfo(argBytesMsg);
 var cmsFirmado = new SignedCms(infoContenido);
 var cmsFirmante = new CmsSigner(argCertFirmante)
  { IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly };
 cmsFirmado.ComputeSignature(cmsFirmante, true);
 return cmsFirmado.Encode();
```

I want the equivalent to this:

- openssl smime -sign -signer ebookingv4.crt -inkey ebookingv4.key -out ticket.xml.cms -in ticket.xml -outform DER -nodetach
- openssl base64 -in ticket.xml.cms -out ticket.xml.cms.base64

[Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3852.txt)
With Net Core 2.0 and this nuget package i was worked fine for me:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms"
Version="4.4.0-beta-24913-01" /> <PackageReference
Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs"
Version="4.5.0-preview1-26119-06" /> <PackageReference
Include="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates"
Version="4.4.0-beta-24913-01" />
```

Comment: Do you want to have it with .net-core for cross-platform or for Windows only?

Comment: yes in .net-core for cross-platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignedCms is not available in .NET Core 1.0 or 1.1; nor will it be in 2.0.  (**Edit**: it will be available in the upcoming 2.1 release).

If you only care about writing data (which is much easier than reading it) you could implement a limited form of it using just RSA.SignData.

SignedCms produces a DER encoded CMS signed-data value ([RFC 5652, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5)), which is

```
SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
    certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
    crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos
}

DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers ::= SET OF DigestAlgorithmIdentifier
SignerInfos ::= SET OF SignerInfo
```

In order to write one you'll need to understand how to write data according to the Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER), which is [ITU-T X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-200811-S) (though it builds a lot on ASN.1, and makes references to ASN.1, which is [ITU-T X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-200811-S)).

Imagine you wanted to sign "Hello" with SHA-2-256 / RSA+SHA-2-256.  Of course, we don't have strings in cryptography, so this is the byte sequence `48 65 6C 6C 6F`.

```
// SEQUENCE (SignedData)
30 xa [ya [za]]
   // INTEGER (Version=1)
   02 01 01
   // SET (OF DigestAlgorithmIdentifier (digestAlgorithms))
   31 xb [yb [zb]]
      // SEQUENCE (DigestAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier)
      30 xc [yc [zc]]
         // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 == SHA-2-256)
         06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01
   // SEQUENCE (EncapsulatedContentInfo)
   30 xd [yd [zd]]
      // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 == pkcs7-data)
      06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 07 01
      // CONTEXT SPECIFIC 0 - CONSTRUCTED
      A0 xe [ye [ze]]
         // OCTET STRING (the data goes here)
         04 05 48 65 6C 6C 6F // "Hello"
   // CONTEXT SPECIFIC 0 - CONSTRUCTED (CertificateSet (certificates))
   A0 xf [yf [zf]]
      [cert.RawData goes here, which is already DER encoded]
      [do you have an intermediate you want to share?
        okay, write intermediate.RawData here; repeat]
   // skip the crls.
   // SET (OF SignerInfo (singerInfos))
   31 xg [yg [zg]]
      // SEQUENCE (SignerInfo)
      30 xh [yh [zh]]
         // INTEGER (Version=1)
         02 01 01
         // SEQUENCE (IssuerAndSerialNumber)
         30 xi [yi [zi]]
            // SEQUENCE (Issuer)
            [cert.IssuerName.RawData]
            // OCTECT STRING (SerialNumber)
            02 xj [yj [zj]]
               [cert.GetSerialNumberBytes() (see note "j")]
         // SEQUENCE (DigestAlgorithm (digestAlgorithm))
         30 xk [yk [zk]]
            // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 == SHA-2-256)
            06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01
         // skip signedAttrs
         // SEQUENCE (DigestEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier)
         30 xl [yl [zl]]
            // OBJECT IDENTIFIER (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 == rsaEncryption)
            06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 
            // NULL (rsaEncryption says parameters must be explicit NULL)
            05 00
         // OCTECT STRING (signature)
         04 xm [ym [zm]]
            [rsa.SignData(
                 new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F },
                 HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                 RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)]
         // skip unsignedAttrs
```

Now we're done and we can close off all the missing lengths.  The signature size is a function of the RSA key.  Let's assume it's a 2048-bit key, that makes a 2048-bit signature, or 256 bytes.  256 is 0x100, which is bigger than 0x7F, so we have to break it up into two length bytes and one length-length byte: So the "m" series of bytes is `80 01 00`.

The "l" series is complete, it contained 13 bytes, so `0D` (no y or z byte).

"k" is complete at 11 bytes (`0B`).

"j" depends on how long the serial number is.  My certificate has serial number `9B 5D E6 C1 51 26 A5 8B`, but you're not supposed to write it down as a negative number (first byte has the high bit set), so it needs a padding byte, making the content `00 9B 5D E6 C1 51 26 A5 8B`, and therefore the length 9 (`09`).

"i" depends on the length of the issuer name. Mine came out to a 141 byte array (already DER encoded), plus our serial number (9 bytes + tag + length == 11 bytes) => 152 bytes (0x98).  Since 0x98 is greater than 0x7F we have to length-prefix it: `81 98`.

Now "h" is done. (3 + (1 + 2 + 152) + (1 + 1 + 11) + (1 + 1 + 13) + (1 + 3 + 256) => 446 = 0x1BE => `82 01 BE`.

"g" is (1 + 3 + 446) => 450 = 0x1C2 `82 01 C2`.

"f" is the sum of all the certs you encoded. Mine came out to 683 = 0x2AB (`82 02 AB`)

"e" is 7 (`07`)

"d" is 11 + (1 + 1 + 7) = 20 = 0x14 (`14`)

"c" is 11 (`0B`)

"b" is (1 + 1 + 11) = 13 (`0D`)

"a" is 3 + (1 + 1 + 13) + (1 + 1 + 11) + (1 + 3 + 683) + (1 + 3 + 450) = 1172 = 0x494 (`82 04 94`).

```
30 82 04 94  02 01 01 31    0D 30 0B 06  09 60 86 48
01 65 03 04  02 01 30 14    06 09 2A 86  48 86 F7 0D
01 07 01 A0  07 04 05 65    6C 6C 6F A0  82 02 AB ...
...cert.RawData...
31 82 01 C2  30 82 01 BE    02 01 01 30  81 98 ...
...cert.IssuerName.RawData...
02 09 00 9B  5D E6 C1 51    26 A5 8B 30  0B 06 09 60
86 48 01 65  03 04 02 01    30 0D 06 09  2A 86 48 86
F7 0D 01 01  01 05 00 04    80 01 00 ... signature ...
```

If you go this route, you'll be assisted by tools like `openssl asn1parse -i -dump -inform DER < your.signed.cms` or [ASN.1 Editor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor), or other such DER reader/rendering tools.

Answer (score 3):

According the `Apisof.Net`, both classes [`SignedCms`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms) and [`CmsSigner`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner) wouldn't be ported to .Net Core. What you can do is two things here:

- Wait for a 2.0 version of .Net Core, so you'll be able to use [`PrivateKey` property](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.PrivateKey), and use the `AsymmetricAlgorithm` object to sign the data
- Or you can use [`extension` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.aspx) [`GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2)`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2)):

  ```
  public byte[] Sign(string message)
  {
      using (var key = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
      {
          return key.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message),
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
      }
  }
  ```

[`HashAlgorithmName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithmname.aspx) has static names for algorithms and [`RSASignaturePadding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsasignaturepadding.aspx) has default objects for padding.